# Access Nested DateTime Object Attribute

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to access the `date` string in the following nested object.

```
["studyDate"]=>
    object(Date)#55 (1) {
      ["date"]=>
      object(DateTime)#58 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "2013-05-31 14:43:00.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(16) "America/New_York"
      }
    }
```

This is being returned in a `$previousExam` variable, so I am trying.
`$previousExam{0}->study_date->date`

This gives me:

```
2016-06-08 10:27:45 object(DateTime)#163 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-06-07 14:41:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
```

This is where i am stuck. Trying `$previousExam{0}->study_date->date->date` returns `NULL`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you want to access string `"2013-05-31 14:43:00"` from `date` property?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes

Comment: `date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s)` is what I needed, but this was a duplicate apparently.

Comment: @DannySullivan Yes it is a dupe. But the code output was also a mean trap :P